# How to search files from directory using filename?

Tags: c#, file, filesystems

I have a file name say 'abc' in folder C:\Demo\output. Now i have another folder C:\Demo\base contaning abc.xml and abc.xsd . Using file name 'abc' how to ensure whether file in another folder exist with both extensions?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Directory.GetFiles()` with search pattern.

Here is a small example:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Demo\base ", "abc.*");
```

More information you can find on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Directory.GetFiles(RootPath, "abc.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)